# workspace in tfs

Tags: tfs, workspace

do needed to create any project in the seperate workspace?
are there the official naming convention for TFS workspaces?
what is usage multi workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workspace simply maps one or more TFS paths to a spot on the disk.  You can map at any level within TFS that you would like.  For example, you could map

```
$/  to a path
$/ProjectName to a path
$/ProjectName/Folder1/Folder1 to a path
```

Multiple workspaces are used  if you need logical separation of code.  Some examples of where you might use multiple workspaces:

- You are working on code for more than one customer at a time, and don't want to mix things up.
- You need to work in multiple branches at the same time (for example, bug-fix and next version)

The key thing to remember about multiple workspaces is that you have to consciously choose to move from one to the other.  In my experience, most of the time, you can get away with a single workspace mapped to `$/`.

Comment: This is a request to elaborate more on: " is that you have to consciously choose to move from one to the other."

Comment: How to do that? 1. (using  UI ) Is chossing the "Workspace" from combobox  sufficient ? 2. How to do it from command prompt?

Comment: You have to consciously choose by selecting the workspace from the combobox, versus just changing directories in the source tree.

Answer (score 0):

TFS will have problems if a workspace is mapped to a higher level directory than other workspaces so to avoid this I create a directory like c:\tfsroot and then match each branch to subdirectories under this directory.